Error 404 trying to execute local AI (oLlAMA-PHI3)
I get a 404 error everytime i run this code
when it reaches aiChatService.GetStreamingChatMessageContentsAsync(chatHistory).
I've tried to reinstall the service and the respective AI but nothing works. any ideas??
using Microsoft.SemanticKernel;
using Microsoft.SemanticKernel.ChatCompletion;

using var httpClient = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:11434"),
};

// Create a kernel with OpenAI chat completion
#pragma warning disable SKEXP0010
Kernel kernel = Kernel.CreateBuilder()
                    .AddOpenAIChatCompletion(
                        modelId: "phi3:3.8b",
                        httpClient: httpClient,
                        apiKey: "non required")
                    .Build();

var aiChatService = kernel.GetRequiredService<IChatCompletionService>();
var chatHistory = new ChatHistory([new ChatMessageContent(AuthorRole.System, "Sos un asistente de programación de C#")]); ;

while (true)
{
    // Get user prompt and add to chat history
    Console.WriteLine("Your prompt:");
    var userPrompt = Console.ReadLine();
    chatHistory.Add(new ChatMessageContent(AuthorRole.User, userPrompt));

    // Stream the AI response and add to chat history
    Console.WriteLine("AI Response:");
    var response = "";
    await foreach (var item in
        aiChatService.GetStreamingChatMessageContentsAsync(chatHistory))
    {
        Console.Write(item.Content);
        response += item.Content;
    }
    chatHistory.Add(new ChatMessageContent(AuthorRole.Assistant, response));
    Console.WriteLine();
}

I've tried to reinstall oLlama service and AI but nothing works.
System.ClientModel.ClientResultException: 'Service request failed.
Status: 404 (Not Found)


Had same issue. Here is alternate sample from the original authors.
The authors informed that the AddOpenAIChatCompletion() has a bug and we need to use AddOllamaChatCompletion().
This approach uses the Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Connectors.Ollama package for a better connection experience to Ollama, so you'll need to add that to your project as well.
The following link has the complete updated sample that was posted as a sample code on MSFT site.
https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/41317#issuecomment-2448142930
